# ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt' When using AWS Lambda and Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I'm currently trying to set up a basic Lambda function in python using AWS CDK and Python, and want to be able to include external libraries in my Lambda code. This is what I've got so far:

```
from constructs import Construct
import aws_cdk as core
from aws_cdk import (
    Stack,
    aws_lambda as _lambda,
    aws_apigateway as apigw,
)


class SportsTeamGeneratorStack(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)
        
        my_lambda = _lambda.Function(self, 'HelloHandler',
            runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9,
                code=_lambda.Code.from_asset("lambda",
                    bundling= core.BundlingOptions(
                        image=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9.bundling_image,
                        command=[
                            "bash", "-c",
                            "pip install --no-cache -r requirements.txt -t /asset-output && cp -au . /asset-output"
                        ],
                    ),
                ),
            handler='hello.handler',
        )

        apigw.LambdaRestApi(
            self, 'Endpoint',
            handler=my_lambda,
        )
```

Whenever I run cdk synth just for sanity, I'm getting this error: ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'. I'm brand new to using docker and AWS Lambda, but I've seen something about creating a docker file and copying over files to the docker image in another post, although I'm not entirely sure if that applies when doing things with AWS as this source:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-image.html

says that "AWS provides a Dockerfile for each of the base images to help with bundling your container image". I have enabled file sharing for the top level project directory using docker, so I don't think that the issue. Also I'm a bit confused if I have to use Amazon ECR here or if this will allow me to include external dependencies in my Lambda code. I'm assuming I somehow have to just bring in the requirements.txt file into the docker image template provided by AWS, but not sure how to do that. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, do you have a `requirements.txt` file in he asset folder?

Comment: does the requirements.txt file have to go in the "lambda" folder in my case?

Comment: Yes, it should be present in the asset folder.

Answer (score 0):

can you try to add `user="root"` as an option to the BundlingOptions?

```
my_lambda = _lambda.Function(self, 'HelloHandler',
            runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9,
                code=_lambda.Code.from_asset("lambda",
                    bundling= core.BundlingOptions(
                        image=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9.bundling_image,
                        command=[
                            "bash", "-c",
                            "pip install --no-cache -r requirements.txt -t /asset-output && cp -au . /asset-output"
                        ],
                        user="root",
                    ),
                ),
            handler='hello.handler',
        )
```